# Get URI from image captured with camera

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to populate a RecyclerView with images captured with camera. Whenever I capture a new picture, I want to be added to the RecyclerView and to update the RecyclerView.

The RecyclerView works good for TextViews (for example) but it doesn't show the Imageviews. I think the problem appears when I try to get the URI of the image captured.

I haven't find too many solutions for this topic so I'm asking you guys.

This is the model class.

```
public class Attachment {
private Uri image;
private String text;

public Attachment(Uri image, String text) {
    this.image = image;
    this.text = text;
}

public Uri getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}
```

This is the Adapter.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Attachment> lista;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public ListViewAdapter(List<Attachment> lista, Context context) {
    this.lista = lista;
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageURI(lista.get(position).getImage());
    holder.textView.setText(lista.get(position).getText());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.listviewAttachmentImageView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}

public void update(List<Attachment> newList) {
    lista.clear();
    lista.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

Here I pass the intent.

```
buttonAddAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                startActivityForResult(intent,CAM_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here I initialize the RecyclerView.

```
    list=new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter=new ListViewAdapter(list, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter.update(list);
```

This is the onActivityResult method (the result of clicking the camera button).

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Attachment att = new Attachment (uri, "BUNA");
        list.add(att);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the update method directly to the class, not withing the viewholder class

Answer (score 0):

In your Attachment model change image to the type Uri

```
public class Attachment { 
    private Uri image; 
    public Attachment(Uri image) { this.image = image; } 
    public Uri getImage() { return image; }
```

Next in onActivityResult after your if statement do

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
Attachment att = new Attachment (uri);
List<Attachment> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(att);
.... = New ListViewAdapter(list, context);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Attachment att = new Attachment (uri);
    List<Attachment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(att);

    adapter=new ListViewAdapter(list,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

} }

Dont set the imageView yet.

In your adapter class onBind

```
holder.imageView.setImageUri(lista.get(position).getImage());
```

Comment: I've made the changes, it's not crushing anymore but the RecyclerView doesn't show any picture

Comment: Post the relevant code on pastebin and share the link so i can take a look at it. But before that ensure you set a layoutmanager for the recyclerview. recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this); recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);

Comment: Also, what elements does  R.layout.listview_layout contain

Comment: The layoutmanager is already set into onCreate method. Here is the link https://pastebin.com/u/CNego

Comment: Add recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter); to your onActivityResult

Comment: I justi figured out that I forgot that, but still not working.

Comment: Move list = new ArrayList<>(); , adapter=new ListViewAdapter(list,this); and recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter) to the onCreate. Now you'll only have Uri uri = intent.getData(); Attachment att = new Attachment (uri); list.add(att); in your onActivityResult. Ensure you make the list a global variable at the top of the class, and instantiate it before assigning the adapter.

Comment: Also, just to clarify you can post your full activity. So I'll know if something's missing somewhere

Comment: Check the link again

Comment: I still can't find anything, paste your layout activity_income then add this method to your adapter class: private void update(List<Attachment> newList) { lista.clear(); lista.addAll(newList); notifyDatasetChanged(); } then return to onActivityResult and call this method like this : adapter.update(list);

Answer (score 0):

Add recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter); to your onActivityResult